# is having a folder with a lot of large image files going to slow down visual studio web project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, image

i just included a new directory in the project.  in that directory are a number of image files (some large).  it seems to have slowed down VS2008 alot.  (Not sure if its a red herring)

should this be expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of keeping VS a little snappier during development, right click on the folder and click "Exclude From Project" so as to not delete it, but not force VS to load it every time.

Not a perfect solution, but only including the folder for builds or when VS absolutely needs it WILL save you time.